# Position HTML imagem não rolar com a tela

Tags: html5, css3, posicionamento

Estou criando um layout em que o conteúdo fica em cima de uma imagem, porém percebi que ao rolar a página essa imagem rola junto! por favor alguém pode ajudar? Tks. 
Lá vai código html:

```
    <section id="corpo-topo" class="row">
    <div id="corpo-img">
        <img id="background-img" src="image/palestra.jpg">
        <div id="rede-social">

        </div>
        <!--Slide-->
        <figure id="box-img">
            <a id="prev" href="javascript:menos()"> < </a> 
            <a id="next" href="javascript:mais()"> > </a>
            <a id="aimg"><img id="img-slide"></a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="corpo" class="row">
    <div id="formulario">
        <img id="icone-img" src="image/icone-cv.png">
        <form id="form">
            <center><h1 id="form-frase">Clique no botão abaixo para enviar o seu Currículo.</h1>
            <a href="#modal"><button id="button-enviar">ENVIE SEU CURRÍCULO</button></a></center>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#menu{
    margin:0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding:5px 15%;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#corpo-img{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:100%;
}

#background-img{
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#corpo-img > #rede-social{
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    margin-left:0px;
    top:70%;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#rede-social ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 0%;
}

#rede-social ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 5% 0;
}

#box-img{
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    margin:0;
    top:70%;
    /*width:100%;
    height:100%;*/
    padding-top:2%;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi @Sarah, não ficou claro o resultado que voce espera, consegue esclarecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigada a todos!
Consegui resolver assim:
Estava usando `position:relative` para a imagem que fica por baixo, e `position:absolute` nos elementos que ficam sobre ela e controlava o posicionamento desses elementos com `left` e `top`. Resolvi usando `position:absolute` e `z-index:0` na imagem que fica por baixo e nos elementos usei `position:absolute` e `z-index:1`. Assim:

```
#corpo-img{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:0;
   width:100%;
}
#background-img{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#corpo-img > #rede-social{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sarah,

Sua pergunta está muito confusa, mas o seu problema deve estar aqui:

```
#corpo-img > #rede-social{
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    margin-left:0px;
    top:70%;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#box-img{
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    margin:0;
    top:70%;
    /*width:100%;
    height:100%;*/
    padding-top:2%;
}
```

Remova a tag `position: absolute;` de cada uma das duas definições acima, teste e verifique se resolve seu problema. Somente lembrando que `position: absolute;` irá deixar o elemento praticamente fixo na tela, juntamente com as tags `left` e `top` você irá fixar a proporção que a imagem ficará sendo exibida.